How to interrupt or prevent user sign up in wordpress using digits plugin?
I am creating a custom script where when successfully sign up, it will pass data to a third party api curl.
The sign up flow using digits plugin currently are, user will be prompted to insert their contact number, email, name and password and upon clicking continue button, user will be prompted to verify by insert the otp code send to their phone number via sms. And upon success, their register data will be passed to the third party api curl and also user data are inserted into the wordpress table.
So what I need to do now is, before user can proceed to insert the otp code/before the user data are created in the wordpress table, I need to first verify if their data already exist in the third party system. If their data already exist then I will need to prompt error and user can't proceed with the registration/their data will not be created in the wordpress table.
In my script file, the code are as below inside custom-hook.php file;
<?php

add_action('digits_before_register_user', 'custom_digits_before_register', 1, 1);

function log_debug($process_name, $reference_id = null, $request, $response, $status = null, $updated_at = '0000-00-00 00:00:00' )
{
    global $wpdb;
    $wpdb->insert('log_hook', [
        'process_name' => $process_name, // This can be the function name, etc.
        'reference_id' => $reference_id, // This can be the order ID, customer ID, etc.
        'request' => $request, // The request message
        'response' => $response, // The response message
        'status' => $status, // The status of the process 1 = success, 0 = failed
        'created_at' => CURRENT_DATETIME,
        'updated_at' => $updated_at
    ]);
}

function custom_digits_before_register($user_data) {
    // Extract data from the registration process
    $data = [
        'phone_number' => $user_data['countrycode'] . $user_data['mobile'],
        'email' => $user_data['email'],
    ];

    // Log: for before register user details
    log_debug('custom_digits_before_register', '', '', json_encode($data), 1);

    wp_send_json_error(['message' => 'Unable to validate data at this time. Please try again later.']);
    exit;
}

log_debug is a function that insert data into the log table for debugging purpose.
When I tried the register flow with above hook, after insert the details (contact number, email, name and password) and then click on the continue button, the otp number are still sent to my number and the hook are not triggered as no log data are inserted in the log table. Since the hook not triggering, so I cannot proceed with the checking with third party api.
Aside from digits_before_register_user, I also tried digits_before_otp_verification, digits_validate_otp and digits_custom_validation suggested by chatgpt but also not working.
I tried to check their documentation at documentation link but it shows error.
Would really appreciate if someone have experience of using this plugin. I don't know the structure of this plugin's code. And I only have access to the custom-hook.php file to add function here.
Or if there are any other workaround that didn't cross my mind would also be appreciated.
Thank you in advance!
Edit:
Here is the create table query for log_hook
CREATE TABLE `log_hook` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `process_name` longtext DEFAULT NULL,
  `reference_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'example user_id/order_id/member_code etc for reference',
  `request` longtext DEFAULT NULL,
  `response` longtext DEFAULT NULL,
  `status` int(11) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT '0: failed, 1: success',
  `created_at` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
  `updated_at` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00' ON UPDATE current_timestamp(),
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb3 COLLATE=utf8mb3_general_ci;


This is one of the rare times a good question is being asked. I don't have an answer for you, but 2FA is already a solved problem. Wordfence has built-in support for 2FA, is there anything in particular stopping you from using their solution?

@maiorano84 Thanks for the suggestion! However in this case, I’m kind of tied to using the Digits plugin since it’s already set up and integrated by my company. Switching plugins isn’t really an option right now.
What I’m trying to do is figure out how to interrupt the registration flow in Digits to check with a third-party system before the user completes the OTP step. If you’ve worked with Digits or know a workaround for this, I’d love to hear your thoughts. Thanks again for chiming in!

Understood! I had a sneaking suspicion there was company motivation on using a particular solution, but figured I'd ask. I've never personally worked with Digits before, or tried to interrupt the login flow by hand. There might be someone here who might be able to provide better direction, but in lieu of that, my only recommendation would be to check into the Wordfence source code and look into how they handle the OTP login mechanism. While you might not use Wordfence directly, their source code may contain an approach you can work into your own system.

"I only have access to…" - you should really expand your access then in order to find where in the plugin the action you are trying to prevent is really happening. This is one of those cases where (temporarily) hacking core or a plugin is a good idea, since documentation isn’t always correct, up to date or even existent.

@ChrisHaas I understand that digging into the plugin’s core files would make this a lot easier, since documentation isn’t always reliable. I do have access to view the plugin code, but unfortunately, I’m restricted to adding or modifying code only within the custom-hook.php file. Directly editing the plugin files isn’t an option for me.
If you’ve got any tips on how to trace where specific actions are happening in the plugin or how to make the most of hooks in a situation like this, I’d really appreciate it. Thanks for taking the time to share your thoughts!

@Lovi, are you working on production only then? There’s no backup, dev, local, etc. then?

Use below the code. There is no add_action('digits_before_register_user', 'custom_digits_before_register', 1, 1);  hook in that plugin
add_action('user_register', 'custom_digits_before_register', 1, 1);

instead of
 add_action('digits_before_register_user', 'custom_digits_before_register', 1, 1);


Thanks for pointing it out, I already fixed the code in the question but still the hook doesn't fire regardless

share the log_hook table structure. May be some fields doesn't has default value

Updated the question with the log_hook table structure for your reference.

@Lovi, Please check updated answer

but user_register triggers after user data created/inserted into the Wordpress table. I need something that can trigger before that to do further checking before it can proceed with either create the user or throw error

Try this hook add_action('register_new_user', 'custom_digits_before_register', 1, 1);

register_new_user hook also triggered after a new user registration has been recorded. but I tested, the hook not triggered. i tried user_register hook, it can be triggered but this is not the hook that I want.
